# Need help in setting up a frontend monorepo for vue and nuxt using yarn workspaces and lerna

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, eslint, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to setup a monorepo for a frontend project using yarn workspaces and lerna.
There will be a shared component library for all the app packages in it.

The project structure looks something like this:

```sh
root
├── lerna.json
├── package.json
└── packages
   ├── ui-library
   │   ├── src/main.js
   │   ├── dist/library.common.js  
   │   └── package.json
   └── app
```

When I import the `ui-library` in my `app` it gives me all sorts of lint errors.

---

#### packages/ui-library

1. is a regular vue project created by `@vue/cli`.

   `vue create ui-library`
2. exposes the auto generated component `src/App.vue` from `src/main.js`

   `export { default as App } from './App'`
3. I've added a script to build the project as a [library](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library)

   `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name library src/main.js`
4. The build script generates `dist/library.common.js` along with other stuff.

In the `ui-library/package.json`,

```json
{
  "name": "@<org>/ui-library",
  "version": "0.0.1-alpha",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./dist/library.common.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name library src/main.js",
  },
  .
  .
  .
}
```

---

#### packages/app

1. It's a nuxt project created by `npx create-nuxt-app app`.
2. I've installed the local ui-library package like this

   `yarn workspace app add @<org>/ui-library@0.0.1-alpha`

It finishes successfully.

I haven't done anything here other than importing the App component in `pages/index.vue`  like this

```html
<template>
  <app />
</template>

<script>
import { App } from '@<org>/ui-library'

export default {
  components: {
    App
  }
}
</script>
```

But the app fails to run because of **lint errors**.

```sh
$ yarn workspace app dev
.
.
app: path\to\packages\ui-library\dist\library.common.js
app:    88:10  error  Unexpected newline between function and ( of function call
                                  no-unexpected-multiline
app:    97:42  error  '_unused_webpack_default_export' is assigned a value but never used
                                  no-unused-vars
app:   102:17  error  'module' is defined but never used
                                  no-unused-vars
.
.
app:    97:42  error  '_unused_webpack_default_export' is assigned a value but never used
                                  no-unused-vars
app:   102:17  error  'module' is defined but never used
                                  no-unused-vars'HelloWorldvue_type_style_index_0_id_b9167eee_scoped_true_lang_css_' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
app:   449:5   error  'Appvue_type_style_index_0_lang_css_' is assigned a value but never used                                 no-unused-vars
app: ✖ 17 problems (17 errors, 0 warnings)
app:   1 error and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

What's the way of ignoring these lint errors or is my approach incorrect?
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can ignore files using using .eslintignore if that's external library

refer : https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#ignoring-files-and-directories

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am currently on the somewhat same issue.

Comment: I'm currently in a situation where I need to decide whether I should go with the Monorepo approach or not. that would be awesome if you could share your suggestions.

Comment: It depends, initially I faced a few roadblocks in this approach because maybe it was not much adopted at that time or maybe I wasn't able to find good reference material but now it has become a defacto approach for me where we need a micro frontend architecture. And module federation is really sugar on top of it.

Comment: @mostafa Now instead of shared components library, the application is divided into modules (read DDD). Each module is responsibility of a developer or a team and whatever needs to be shared is done using module federation.

Comment: If your projects have multiple domains (from DDD). Go for it

Answer (score 0):

Now instead of shared components library, the application is divided into modules (read DDD). Each module is responsibility of a developer or a team and whatever needs to be shared is done using module federation.